# Group theory question in preparation for exam

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to prove (for self-study) that if $A \approx A'$ and $B \approx B'$, then $A$ x $B \approx A'$ x $B'$.

I'm at the last leg of my preparation for my test and am just smoked.

Could someone help me out please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $f:A\to A'$ and $g:B\to B'$ be isomorphisms. What’s the one natural way to try to define an isomorphism $h:A\times B\to A'\times B'$ using $f$ and $g$? Where should $h$ send $\langle a,b\rangle$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$? There’s really only one natural thing to try. And once you have the right map $h$, verifying that it’s an isomorphism really is very easy.

Comment: Ok, I've got $h(a,b)=(a',b')$, and $f(a)=a'$, and $f(b)=b'$.

Comment: And then I've got $h((a,b)(c,d))=h(a',b')h(c',d')$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes, that map is the only reasonable one to try. You’ve left out a few steps in checking that it’s a homomorphism, though: $$h(\langle a,b\rangle\langle c,d\rangle)=h(\langle ac,bd\rangle=\langle f(ac),g(bd)\rangle=\ldots\;.$$ And don’t forget to check that it’s an isomormphism, not just a homomorphism; the easiest way to do that is to check that its kernel is trivial.

Comment: Got it. A nice tie-in of concepts!